# How to run and compile a cairo file in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, compiler-errors, cairo

I wanted to use cairo library for c++ graphics. I included the libraries using

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
```

and further I installed GLX-Dock(Cairo Dock with OpenGL) using Ubuntu open software center and used the code in http://cairographics.org/FAQ/ and compiled with command

```
g++ trial.cpp
```

but it gives me the following error

```
fatal error: cairo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

How should i compile and run the file?

Moreover can someone recommend easy to learn graphics library with more features. I tried using OpenGL but found it difficult to understand.

Comment: right after the code in the website it tells you how to compile. it's not `g++ trial.cpp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the FAQ again: http://cairographics.org/FAQ/#compilation_flags

This will get you started:

```
g++ test.c \`pkg-config --libs --cflags cairo\` -o test
```

Run it with:

```
./test
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this Solution Works

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
```

And then:

```
sudo npm install processing -g
```