# Compiling a cairomm example under Ubuntu

Tags: c++, drawing, cairo

I am trying to compile an example that comes with `cairomm` version 1.0 (which comes with Ubuntu 14.0 that I am using). Following the [FAQ](http://cairographics.org/FAQ/#compilation_flags) (which helped the author of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11918274/2725810) question), I did:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig

g++ -o cairo_test01 $(pkg-config --cflags --libs cairo) cairo_test01.cpp
```

(putting `cairomm` after `--libs` does not change the result)

Getting the error:

```
cairo_test01.cpp:13:29: fatal error: cairomm/context.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cairomm/context.h>
```

`pkg-config` version 0.26 is installed.

**UPDATE**: Resolved!

Thanks to the comment, I was able to compile without `pkg-config`. After putting cairommconfig.h into the current directory and locating all the headers, the command looks like this:

g++ -I ~/boost_1_59_0 -I /usr/include/cairomm-1.0/ -I /usr/include/cairo/ -I /usr/include/sigc++-2.0/ -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include/ -I /usr/include/freetype2/ cairo_test01.cpp -o cairo_test01 -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcairomm-1.0

Comment: Well you don't actually seem to be linking with the cairomm library?

Comment: When I say -lcairomm, it says that there is no such thing: cannot find -lcairomm.

Comment: Have you tried looking for it? E.g. `find /usr -iname 'lib*cairomm*.so'`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you!